# Forge - Retrieve BIM360 Transmittals information

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to retrieve **TRANSMITTALS** data from BIM360 through **Forge** and its APIs, but so far, I couldn't find specific documentation about it. I am trying to understand where this information is kept, and which API should I use to get the data.

Is there any documentation someone can refer on this topic? A developer’s guide, or the API references somehow similar to the ones that exist for Issues, Checklists or RFIs? https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/

Thank you,

Hector

Comment: As replied on Autodesk forum, Unfortunately, as I know, Transmittals API has not been exposed. Please bear with me checking with engineer team on the status of this API.

Comment: I got to know it is true Transmittal API is on the near plan, which means it has not been available. We cannot guarantee until it is available in the  final release. your patience is highly appreciated.